# Is there any macro to differentiate between WinCE emulator and WinCE device?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-mobile, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I need to perform some file operations on WinCE platform.
The paths of file differ in Device compared to Emulator.
So i need to choose file according to the environment, like below.

```
#if defined(WINCE_EMULATOR) //This macro is just for illustration
   #define path ".\Storage Card\\1.txt" //Emulator configuration
#else
   #define path "\\My Documents\Storage Card\\1.txt" //Device configuration
#endif
```

Is there any macro to differentiate between WinCE emulator and WinCE device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a macro to check this, and couldn't be - the compiler has no idea what target you're going to run on.  You have to do a run-time check using something like [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932539.aspx) with SPI_GETOEMINFO and look for emulator-specific text (IIRC it returns something like "Microsoft DeviceEmulator").

Comment: Is there any OS macro like OS_WINXP or OS_WINMOBILE ?

Comment: There are macros like UNDER_CE, WIN32_PLATFORM_PSPC, and WIN32_PLATFORM_WFSP.